# GetVersionEx function for Windows 8.1 and upper (fasm)

Tags: winapi, fasm

I am writting application in fasm and have problem with determinating Windows version 8.1 and upper. Functions `GetVersionEx` and `Version Helper` give me Windows 8. As MSDN says, I must target my application via changing manifest file in Visual Studio, but I'm not using VS, so what should I do?

Comment: See [Understanding Manifest Generation for C/C++ Programs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235542.aspx) to get going. Use the [/MANIFESTINPUT (Specify Manifest Input)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195770.aspx) linker switch to embed the manifest. In case you are using FASM to link the object code, you'll have to instruct it to embed the resource, using the [`resdata manifest`](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32#1.8) macro instruction.

Comment: MSDN does not say you have to do this in VS.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is the version where the behavior of `GetVersionEx()` changed. You have to manifest your executable, and specify compatibility with specific OS versions in that manifest, in order for `GetVersionEx()` to report those version numbers correctly. This change in behavior is well-documented on MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any programming environment that allows you to link resources into the compiled executable can be used to create a manifest resource.  All you have to do is write a suitable `.manifest` file for your app that contains the desired XML values, and then link that file's content directly into your application's resources, making sure the resource type is 24 and the resource ID is 1, 2, or 3 (see [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2007/06/26/rt-manifest-resource-and-isolation-aware-enabled.aspx) for details about when to use which ID).  You are not required to use VisualStudio for this.

If, for some reason, you cannot link the manifest directly into your app's resources, you can alternatively save the XML into a file named `<myappname>.exe.manifest` (where `<myappname>` is the actual name of your EXE file) and put it in the same folder as your app.  This is not the preferred approach to manifestation, but it does work.

That being said, there are alternative APIs you can use instead of `GetVersion/Ex()` or `VerifyVersionInfo()`-based helpers to get the correct OS version without dealing with manifestation at all.  Namely, [`RtlGetVersion()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561910.aspx), [`NetServerGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370624.aspx), and [`NetWkstaGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370663.aspx) can be used instead (and all of them have been tested as working in Windows 8.1 and 10).

Answer (score 0):

The manifest file is XML file embedded as Win32 resource. It can also be external file with the name `your.exe.manifest`. Search for examples in internet for sample contents.